# useState in react custom hook always calls the function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have created a custom hook in which one of the state variable gets the initial value from a function (see the example below). When i am referencing the value, it is calling the function and giving back the value returned from function instead of last stored value.

I example below, the initial value of `touched` is the value returned from function `createDefaultValue`. In `handleOnBlur`, i am updating the value of touched. Everytime i call this function, I get the default value for touched instead of the last updated object.

```
const useForm = ({ initialValues = {} }) => {
  const createDefaultValues = (defaultValue) =>
    Object.keys(initialValues).reduce((obj, key) => {
      obj[key] = defaultValue;
      return obj;
    }, {});

  const [touched, setTouched] = React.useState(createDefaultValues(false));

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(touched);
  }, [touched]);

  const handleOnBlur = async (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    setTouched({ ...touched, [name]: true });
  };

  return {touched, handleOnBlur};
}

export default useForm;
```

Usage: in file `form.tsx`

```
import useForm from './useForm';

const Form = (props) => {
  const {touched, handleOnBlur} = useForm({
     initialValues: {name: null, email: null}
  });

  return (
    <>
      <TextField
          id="name"
          helperText={touched.name ? 'Should be valid' : ''}
          error={touched.name}
          onBlur={handleOnBlur}
          onChange={..}
          value={..}
      />
      <TextField
          id="email"
          helperText={touched.email ? 'Should be valid' : ''}
          error={touched.email}
          onBlur={handleOnBlur}
          onChange={..}
          value={..}
       />
    </>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using it?

Comment: i have updated the question with how the custom hook is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show where `handleOnBlur` is called/used, but guessing from your description it sounds like a stale enclosure of the initial `touched` state in the callback. Use a functional state update to enqueue states that update from the previous state value instead of whatever is closed over in callback scope.

It's a trivial change.

```
const handleOnBlur = (e) => {
  const { name } = e.target;
  setTouched(touched => ({
    ...touched,
    [name]: true
  }));
};
```

* Removed the `async` keyword since nothing in `handleOnBlur` is asynchronous and the `await` keyword isn't used.

Comment: Thank you comment Drew. I have something else in handleOnBlur that awaits, thus the reason for async (that has nothing to do with values of touched or does not not rerender the hook). i only added what is relevant to this question. Tried removing all additional logic, and the async, but the issue still remains same.

Comment: @VinodKolla You may need to include more code, enough for a minimal, complete, and reproducible example. What is `TextField` component? Think you could create a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Answer (score 1):

That is because you're calling the function every time your component renders, here:

```js
const [touched, setTouched] = React.useState(createDefaultValues(false));
```

`createDefaultValues` is called on every render. You should do this instead:

```js
const [touched, setTouched] = React.useState();

React.useEffect(() => {
  setTouched(createDefaultValues(false))
}, [initialValues]);

...
```

Comment: Your `createDefaultValues` can also be improved by making it pure and moving it outside your React component.